# why does flutter desktop-embedding throw an error on build?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to run my existing flutter app on windows, so I loaded the lastest flutter-desktop-embedding version, placed my code inside and tried to run it. It soon breaks with an exception:

```
Build process failed. To view the stack trace, please run `flutter run -d windows -v`.

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:28:3)
#1      buildWindows (package:flutter_tools/src/windows/build_windows.dart:82:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      WindowsDevice.buildForDevice (package:flutter_tools/src/windows/windows_device.dart:46:11)
#3      DesktopDevice.startApp (package:flutter_tools/src/desktop_device.dart:87:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      FlutterDevice.runHot (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:416:54)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      HotRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/run_hot.dart:266:39)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:499:37)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:570:18)
#8      _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:71:64)
#9      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#10     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#11     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:137:18)
#12     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:678:45)
#13     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:707:32)
#14     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:522:5)
#15     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:30:15)
#16     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:288:13)
#17     RunCommand.usageValues (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart)
#18     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:71:64)
#19     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#20     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#21     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:137:18)
#22     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:678:45)
#23     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:707:32)
#24     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:522:5)
#25     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:30:15)
#26     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:288:13)
#27     IosProject.isSwift (package:flutter_tools/src/project.dart)
#28     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:71:64)
#29     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#30     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#31     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:137:18)
#32     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:678:45)
#33     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:707:32)
#34     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:522:5)
#35     Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:552:7)
#36     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#37     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#38     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)
#39     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:963:23)
#40     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#41     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#42     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:116:13)
#43     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:173:5)
```

I am developing on the master channel, already made **flutter upgrade** and else I think i did everything else I need to do. Running the example comming with flutter-desktop-embedding does not throw any exception, and it seems that if I copy my lib folder into the examples folder, the app will not build.

Does anyone face this issue too?

Comment: As the error message says, you currently need to build in verbose mode to get the output necessary to see why the underlying native build failed. The `flutter` tool stack trace you have there only indicates that the native build failed; any failure at all in that step would have the same stack.

Comment: did forget to mention that this is the verbose output

Comment: It's definitely not the entire verbose output, because there's absolutely no output from the native build step in what you've shown. It's impossible to debug the problem without the part of the output that indicates what failed in the build.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due Flutter Version to Solve it

1. Open Terminal and Write `flutter upgrade --force`
2. Open Your Windows Flutter Project and Write `flutter run`